# Не работает margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

`margin` не работает и всё. У `p` работает, а у `а` - нет.

```
.block{
    margin-right: 174px;
    p{
        margin-bottom: 32px;
        padding-top: 125px;
        color:#fff;
    }
    a{
        margin-bottom: 32px;
        letter-spacing: 2%;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: $link;
        &:hover{
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У inline-элементов не бывает вертикальных маргинов, делайте элемент блочным или крутите line-height или типа того

Comment: Стоит изучить CSS. В частности свойство display и как при разных значениях работает блочная модель.

Answer (score -1):

Свойство margin схлапывается. Попробуйте у тега `<p>` использовать `padding-bottom` вместо `margin-bottom`.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/887252)

Comment: @SwaD ну вообще это ответ, хоть и неправильный